# is there a fucntion in R to colour code data points on regression of another column?

Tags: r, csv, regression

I am trying to make a regression where there are points of two variables and they are colour coded based on another column that has "Yes" or "NO" in it.

Here is a random example with data I have made up, I hope this okay as I'm not sure how to make repeatable example.

| km | litre | WOF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 133 | 1 | Yes |
| 88 | 2 | Yes |
| 222 | 1 | No |

I have tried something like this by looking at lecture notes but it is not working.

```
cars <- read.csv("random_cardata.csv")

plot(km ~ litre, data = cars, pch = 19, col=c("black", "red")[car$WOF])
```

I am also trying to figure out how to make a legend where on the side it says:

```
"Green = has WOF" and 
"Red = no WOF"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have managed to do it by removing the $ in [car$WOF]. What the eastiest way to  add a legend of "Green = has WOF" and "Red = no WOF"

Comment: See `?legend`. Better still, start using `ggplot`!

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~km, ~litre, ~WOF,
  133L, 1L, "Yes",
  88L, 2L, "Yes",
  222L, 1L, "No"
)

qplot(litre, km, color = WOF, data = data)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

or more comprehensive

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~km, ~litre, ~WOF,
  133L, 1L, "Yes",
  88L, 2L, "Yes",
  222L, 1L, "No"
)

data %>%
  mutate(WOF2 = ifelse(WOF == "Yes", "has WOF", "no WOF")) %>%
  qplot(litre, km, color = WOF2, data = .) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("has WOF" = "green", "no WOF" = "red")) +
  labs(color = "WOF")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, think I am on the right track, just wondering if there is a manual fucntion to change the legend title . Like legend.title or soemthing?

Comment: Manual legend is very dangerous if you change the code and forget to change the manual legend...